# Voltage divider example

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

I have the following voltage divider circuit:
[image]

Now, my goal is to find `U_{L}`.

Altough, I know already the solution (`U_{L}`= 0.5V), I don't understand how to calculate this.
What is the easiest way to solve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can calculate the voltages at the divider points individually. Work your way from the back to the front. It should be fairly obvious that $U_L=U_4/2$. So what's $U_4$? It's determined by the voltage divider formed by the 5k resistor and the 10k in parallel to two 5k resistors in series acting on $U_2$. What's the divider ratio of that? Now work your way the same way from $U_2$ to $U_1$. If you want bonus points (challenge yourself!), derive an algorithm to calculate a general voltage divider chain made from arbitrary resistors Rs1, Rp1, Rs2, Rp2...!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Well, I am an absolute beginner in this field. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: This is a beginners problem. I have no doubts that you can do it. Think about it step by step from the back to the front, because that's all you really need to do. Block out the first three resistors with a piece of paper and look at the last three in isolation. Once you can solve that, use what you have learned on the next stage of the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to solve this?

The easiest way is unlikely to be the most illuminating way.  What I propose is that you first work the problem from basic circuit principles and then explore more powerful solution methods such as, e.g., node voltage analysis, Thevenin equivalent circuit etc.

Start from the right hand side with Ohm's law:

$$I_6 = \frac{U_L}{R_6} = \frac{U_L}{5k\Omega}$$

Now, apply Kirchhoff's current law (KCL) to write:

$$I_5 = I_6$$

and then Ohm's law to write:

$$V_5 = I_5 \cdot R_5 =  I_6 \cdot R_5 = \frac{U_L}{5k\Omega}5k\Omega = U_L$$

Now, apply Kirchhoff's voltage law (KVL) to write:

$$V_4 = V_5 + V_6 = U_L + U_L = 2U_L$$

Repeat this process, 'climbing the ladder' to the left, just as I've started to do,  until you finally reach the voltage source and, at that point, you will have an expression for $U_L$.